# "Localhost refuses to connect" with npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I simply want to work on this Bootstrap project of mine, but I can't because I can't test anything on my local server. In my browser, I get the error 'Localhost refuses to connect'.  And under that it says, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. It's also serving it up on port `3443` automatically for some reason when I thought it usually did on port `3000`.  Even when I type 'localhost:3000' manually into the url bar, it still refuses to connect.  I feel like this is the main part of the problem actually.  I don't think I started having these problems until I downloaded McAfee.  I've since disabled the McAfee Firewall and McAfee Web Advisor in the meantime.  Anyway, I don't know if this helps, but here is the content of my `package.json`, `gulpfile.js`, and my bash terminal output when trying to execute 'npm start', respectively:

```html
{
    "title": "Small Business",
    "name": "startbootstrap-small-business",
    "version": "4.2.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node_modules/.bin/gulp watch"
    },
    "description": "A small business HTML template built with Bootstrap",
    "keywords": [
        "css",
        "sass",
        "html",
        "responsive",
        "theme",
        "template"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/small-business",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-small-business/issues",
        "email": "feedback@startbootstrap.com"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": "Start Bootstrap",
    "contributors": [
        "David Miller (http://davidmiller.io/)"
    ],
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-small-business.git"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
        "jquery": "3.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "2.26.7",
        "del": "^4.1.1",
        "gulp": "4.0.2",
        "merge-stream": "2.0.0"
    }
}
```

```js
"use strict";

// Load plugins
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
const del = require("del");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const merge = require("merge-stream");

// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    },
    port: 3000
  });
  done();
}

// BrowserSync reload
function browserSyncReload(done) {
  browsersync.reload();
  done();
}

// Clean vendor
function clean() {
  return del(["./vendor/"]);
}

// Bring third party dependencies from node_modules into vendor directory
function modules() {
  // Bootstrap
  var bootstrap = gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/bootstrap'));
  // jQuery
  var jquery = gulp.src([
      './node_modules/jquery/dist/*',
      '!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/jquery'));
  return merge(bootstrap, jquery);
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch("./**/*.css", browserSyncReload);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
}

// Define complex tasks
const vendor = gulp.series(clean, modules);
const build = gulp.series(vendor);
const watch = gulp.series(build, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync));

// Export tasks
exports.clean = clean;
exports.vendor = vendor;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = build;
```

```html
[16:32:23] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/HHWebsiteFolder/Bootstrap/startbootstrap-small-business/gulpfile.js
[16:32:23] Starting 'watch'...
[16:32:23] Starting 'clean'...
[16:32:23] Finished 'clean' after 9.64 ms
[16:32:23] Starting 'modules'...
[16:32:23] Finished 'modules' after 60 ms
[16:32:23] Starting 'watchFiles'...
[16:32:23] Starting 'browserSync'...
[16:32:23] Finished 'browserSync' after 21 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.66:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
```

Comment: whats your exact question

Comment: What do I need to do to run my app on my local PORT 3000 like it used to default to?  It no longer runs when I type 'npm start'.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I deleted cookies, browser history, and cached data.  Now once typing 'npm start' in my terminal my app serves up automatically to localhost:3000 instead of localhost:3443, the latter not formerly working at all.  I was having to type '127.0.0.1:3000' into my address bar before it would display anything in Chrome.